# Image in ComboBox only visible in designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, expression-blend

Here's the situation:

I have a combobox within a button,, In expression blend when I add image to combo box item with the cod below, there's no problem apparently, image and textblock are showing well but as I run the proj.((F5)) there'e no sign of image, What I'm doing Wrong???
here's the code I use to add the image:

```
<ComboBoxItem Background="LightCoral" Foreground="Red"
         FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">               
    <CheckBox Name="CoffieCheckBox">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="coffie.jpg" Height="30"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Coffie"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </CheckBox>
```

Any help Is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem showing images (used Uri strings) in a listview in a Silverlight application. They appeared properly in Expression Blend, but were not visible when I started it from Visual studio.

I kept my images in a folder called Images in my project, by setting the "Build action" for my image properties into "Content" fixed the problem. Now they show up when running the application. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, Figured out so, but thanks you cared to answer, I tick you up as a thank you...

Answer (score 1):

One likely problem might be that the image file is in your project folder without being copied to the build folder; `/bin/Release` for example. The application then will not find the file anymore. You can either ensure that the image is being copied when the application is compiled (that alone may not work actually as unqualified URIs make the parser look for resources as far as i know, the designer however does not seem to care) or you can embed the image as a resource. I do not know how to change compile settings in Blend however as i only use Visual Studio...

Comment: this was the most helpful but you're an expert in this site so I tick the other answer up just to encourage him/her to participate more, I'll vote you up as soon as I got the privilege to do so...
Tnx Sir